# Синхронизация веток git на компьютере (phpstorm) и сервере

Tags: git, phpstorm

День добрый, возник вопрос по поводу синхронизации git.
Ситуация следующая:
Есть хост с препродакшеном, на нем уже есть git, работа с которым идет через ssh.
Есть проект в phpstorm с подключенным и настроенным git на локальном ПК (под ОС windows7).

Проблема заключается в том, что создавая ветку и переключаясь на нее в phpstorm для работы, на сервере эта операция не производится, и все изменения, сделанные на локальном ПК и сохраненные, на сервере попадают в ветку master. Как следствие, если в последствии попытаться работать с git на сервере, он будет крайне возмущен большим количеством изменений в файлах на ветке master.

Возможно ли синхронизировать работу git на сервере и локальном ПК, чтобы при переключении веток в phpstorm на сервере производились те же самые операции? Ну и соответственно, при мердже в phpstorm мердж так же произошел на сервере.
Я нашел только вариант отключения автозаливки изменений на сервер и последующий pull на сервере из репозитория. Но это не очень удобно, возможно есть иные варианты?

Comment: Так у вас просто *git push* с параметрами насильно в master заливает? Хотя скорее всего предположить, что на сервере просто нет ветки, которая у вас локально. Проверьте, что выдаёт *git branch -a*.

Comment: Дело как раз в том, что на сервере нет ветки, которую я создаю локально через phpstorm, и соответственно когда я аплодю изменения на сервер, они уходят на master (либо ту ветку, которая активна на сервере), хотя в phpstorm я работаю на отдельной ветке. Вопрос как раз в том, как заставить phpstorm создавать ветку на сервере, помимо локального гита. Покачто нашел решение - аплоадить на сервер всю папку .git, синхронизация работает но как мне кажется это достаточно костыльное решение.

Comment: Крутите параметрами *push*.